# Additional training NLP

Tags: python, nlp

I started working with the Camembert deep learning model, an analogue of Roberta for the French language, and I have a question, how can I retrain such a model for a particular task? Specifically, the task is for the model to learn how to evaluate input sentences for correctness

```
class newModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, numFeatures=768):
        super(newModel, self).__init__()
        self.camembert = CamembertModel.from_pretrained('camembert-base')
        self.GAP = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, numFeatures))
        self.predictionLayer = nn.Linear(numFeatures, 2)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax()

    def forward(self, x):
        camembertFeatures = self.camembert(**tokenized_sentence) # [BS, inputShape] -> [BS, numToken, numFeatures]
        camembertFeatures = camembertFeatures[0]
        GAPvalues = self.GAP(camembertFeatures) # [BS, numToken, numFeatures] -> [BS, 1, numFeatures]
        GAPshape = GAPvalues.shape
        sentenceFeatures = GAPvalues.view(GAPshape[0], GAPshape[2]) # [BS, 1, numFeatures] -> [BS, numFeatures]
        predictions = self.predictionLayer(sentenceFeatures) # [BS, numFeatures] -> [BS, 2]
        predictions = self.softmax(predictions) # [BS, 2] -> [BS, 2]
        return predictions
```

I have built a layer, which needs to be trained, how to do it in the correct way? (it is especially important to understand which optimizer and loss function to use)

Answer (score 0):

If you have built a layer on top of your camembert, i.e. you are trying to finetune it,  you can follow the standard practice for finetuning, which is to freeze the pretrained the large model and only optimizing the layers built on top of it. I believe that for starter an ***MLP*** on top of it will do just fine.

In case of correctness (which is a classification task I believe) you can use a ***Crossentropy*** loss function and an ***adam*** optimizer